# Angularfire Login Ionic App doesnt work on device

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, touchstart

We have been working on an ionic powered game for 6 months now. its ready for the 1.0 beta push now.

We ran in an serious issue. The google login(angularfire based) that people need to use b4 they can play the game stopped working in the final apk and i can't seem to find the source of the problem.

After live debugging on my phone i found out there was 2 warnings in my console,

```
"Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343"
```

And

```
ionic.bundle.js:5193 Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
```

I first thought it had something to do with the overscroll disable for ios

```
 // this fixes the overscroll Apple devices
          if(window.device && device.platform == "IOS"){
            var touchStartEvent;
            $('.scrollable').on({
                touchstart: function(e) {
                    touchStartEvent = e;
                },
                touchmove: function(e) {
                    if ((e.originalEvent.pageY > touchStartEvent.originalEvent.pageY && this.scrollTop == 0) ||
                        (e.originalEvent.pageY < touchStartEvent.originalEvent.pageY && this.scrollTop + this.offsetHeight >= this.scrollHeight))
                        e.preventDefault();
                }
            });  
            }
```

After trying to remove this, still NOTHING has changed.

Now i'm curious if someone had the same issue or some kind of solution? at this time i don't have a plunker of the project (way to much code) and the problem doesn't appear on desktop so i don't see the need for it.
(Is there a plunker needed, i'll make one for sure).

I don't have any idea how i can track or solve the problem at this stage, on desktop i don't see any problem.

---- edit ----

Way to solve this problem was in different direction i expected to find.

1. updated npm, cordova and ionic.
2. did a `ionic state save`
3. did a `ionic platform remove android`
4. did a `ionic platform add android`
5. repeated this until i found out all the missing plugins and all my plugins where re-installed (needed to use the git https link instead of only the name)
6. fixed the problem, and getting a drink.

Comment: what version of angularFire are you using?

Comment: @AaronSaunders
AngularFire 1.0.0
--edit--
Changing to 1.2.0 does not fix the problem...

Comment: you have verified that inapbrowser is installed?

Comment: @AaronSaunders when i try to install the inappbrowser cordova plugin again(to be sure) it tells me it can't find the config.xml ... maybe we are on to something now?

Comment: @AaronSaunders did this list of updates,
npm install npm -g
npm install -g cordova
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
----
Still same problem tho

Comment: `ionic state save` THEN I would remove the platform and then restore it... that should reinstall all plugins

Comment: @AaronSaunders dam you don't know how thankful i am right now! turns out someone in the team F***** Up all of the plugins... fixed it and finally... it works! thanks for pointing me the direction to look for! any way to thank you?

Comment: no problem.. plugins are the root of a lot of issues with cordova